# Ajax send GET, instead of PUT and DELETE with Django backend

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

I have two custom form in HTML:

- first needs to UPDATE first model
- second needs to UPDATE or DELETE second model

[Page screenshot with forms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUhJk.png)

Page loads via link `.../personal/<staff_id>/`.

I have following code for buttons in second form:

Url for buttons:

```
var updateUrl = '../personal/change/{{ profile.user.id }}/'
```

Blue button with name **Изменить** and id="change":

```
$("#change").on("click", function (event) {
      var form = $('#form-profile');
      $.ajax({
          url: updateUrl,
          type: 'PUT',
          method: 'PUT',
          ...
      });
  });
```

Red button with name **Удалить** and id="delete:

```
$("#delete").on("click", function (event) {
      var form = $('#form-profile');
      $.ajax({
          url: updateUrl,
          type: 'PUT',
          method: 'PUT',
          ...
      });
  });
```

When pressing to buttons, page reloads with all form data in url

> personal/<staff_id>?csrfmiddlewaretoken=C5UPpOHIg2LJLbAIJpZHJosBK6Zma7BZjWC9s5TaLRZdlGOCJGsUMq
> T13MbO0wI2&profile_pic=&first_name=Name+3&last_name=Surname+3&email=&phone=&website=&role=методист&description=&delete=

Ajax should have been sent PUT or DELETE request, instead it sends GET request with all parameters.

I tested on postman, Django performs as needed. If DELETE was sent marks User as deleted and returns User. If PUT just updates User and returns updated User

What am I doing wrong?

**UPD:**

I solved problem by doing this:

- Moved out Buttons from *form* container and changed `updateUrl`. As result got 403 forbidden error.
- Added CSRF token to header before Ajax send query, by doing this:

  $.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
  xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
  }
  });

**N.B.**

I'm not what last actions solved problem. I think using Django {% url '...' **params %} instead of spelling url by myself somehow gave me another errors, so I could change my URL structure.

Comment: HTML does not support PUT/PATCH/DELETE requests in a `<form method="...">`, you will need to alter this in AJAX to submit the form as PUT/PATCH/DELETE

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thank you sir for this information. I didn't know. Although, that's not the reason of a problem. But this may help out next time

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add `method:'PUT'` to ajax to make a `put request` like:

```
...
$.ajax({
  ...
  method: 'PUT',
  ...
});
```

And html form cannot be submitted as `delete` or `put`

Comment: I do have both `type: 'PUT'` and `method: 'PUT'`. Unfortunately Its not working(